# Get the most recent backup files

Tags: shell-script, files, backup, filenames, sort

I'm googling for this, but the terms are so generic I'm getting way too many false positives, so what the hey, I'll ask here.  I'm sure there's a simple answer but I don't generally script in *nix.

I'm trying to write a database refresh script to our test environment.  The backups are mounted from an smbfs share, something like `/data/backups/prod`, but the subfolders get a little tricky.  It looks like `myproddbserver/yyyymmdd`, with a bunch of files underneath.

I want to execute a command `restore` that will collect the files with known names from the most recent `yyyymmdd` directory.  For example, if I had:

```
myproddbserver/20130630/foo.bak
myproddbserver/20130630/bar.bak
myproddbserver/20130731/foo.bak
myproddbserver/20130731/bar.bak
```

I would want to restore `myproddbserver/20130731/foo.bak` and `myproddbserver/20130731/bar.bak`.

How would I reliably get those paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a `yyyymmdd` format, a numerical sort will work fine. The fastest way will be using the `sort` command:

```
newest_dir=$(printf '%s\n' myproddbserver/* | sort -rn | head -n1)
```

You can also do this in pure bash:

```
newest=0
for d in myproddbserver/*; do
    (( d > newest )) && newest=$d
done

newest_files=("myproddbserver/$newest/"*)
printf '%s\n' "${newest_files[@]}"
```

The bash version is likely slower, but will handle all possible filenames. The `sort` method will fail if any filenames contain a newline character.

Comment: Works like a champ; exactly what I needed.  Thanks.